# Why always fires OnFailure when return View() to Ajax Form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, .net-3.5, forms-authentication

I'm trying to make a log-in log-off with Ajax supported.

I made some logic in my controller to sign the user in and then return simple partial containing welcome message and log-Off ActionLink my Action method looks like this :

```
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
             //HERE IS THE PROBLEM :(
                return View("LogedInForm", model);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                else
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Content("There were an error !");
            }
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and I'm trying to return this simple partial :

```
 Welcome <b><%= Html.Encode(Model.UserName)%></b>!
 <%= Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") %>
```

and of-course the two partial are strongly-typed to LogOnModel.

**But if i returned `View("PartialName")` i always get `OnFailure` with status code 500.
While if i returned `Content("My Message")` everything is going right.**

so please tell me why i always get this "StatusCode = 500" ??. where is the big mistake ??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return PartialView("LogedInForm", model);
}
```

Make sure that you have a strongly typed `LogedInForm.ascx` in the same view folder as the controller name.

If this doesn't fix the error try using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) in order to see the exact error message which the action returns to the AJAX request.

Comment: Worked very good :)

Thank you but i was reading this book "Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0" to learn and they put the View() instead of PartialView();

Thanks again